# What is this geometric pattern called?

Tags: geometry

What is this geometric pattern called?

[image]

Comment: Image no longer shows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shape formed is approximately a parabola. See [link](http://mathcraft.wonderhowto.com/how-to/create-parabolic-curves-using-straight-lines-0131301/) for some more details about the construction.

Generally, constructions like this seem to be called "geometric string art".

Comment: One can make a parabola by using lines in this manner, but that doesn't make _this_ a parabola.

Comment: @Semiclassical I'm not sure what you're getting at. Is it that this is only an approximation to a parabola?

Comment: You're right. But I just want to know the general name for patterns like this (if there is such a name).

Comment: The general pattern is an envelope. But I'm trying to confirm something, and I may've jumped too quick on you (sorry).

Comment: You were correct initially: It is a parabola. (I thought it was a hyperbola). See Wikipedia's page on [_envelopes_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Envelope_(mathematics)) of curves; this example is given as an animation and discussed in the text.