# Can anyone prove that this is an envelope of a parabola?

Tags: calculus, geometry

[image]
Based on my last question I learned that this is an envelope of a parabola

[What is this geometric pattern called?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/874478/what-is-this-geometric-pattern-called)

But how can I prove it ?

Comment: See also: ["What is the name of this curve?"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/551882/what-is-the-name-of-this-curve/551913#551913)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We try to model the family of lines and then try to infer the envelope.

The guiding lines (left and right arms of the V shape) are
$$
g(t) = u_g \, (1-t) + v_g \, t \quad h(t) = u_h \, (1-t) + v_h \, t
$$
for $t \in [0, 1]$, where $u$ is the start point and $v$ the end point of that line.

A line $f_r$ of the family starts on $g$ and ends on $h$:
$$
f_r(t) = g(r) \, (1-t)  + h(r) \, t
$$
again with the parameter $t \in [0, 1]$.

The envelope is approximated by points where two of the family lines intersect:
$$
\begin{align}
f_r(t) &= f_s(t') \iff \\
g(r) \, (1-t) + h(r) \, t &= g(s) \, (1-t') + h(s) \,t' 
\end{align}
$$

This gives the matrix equation
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
h(r) - g(r) & -(h(s) - g(s))
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
t \\
t'
\end{matrix}
\right]
= 
g(s) - g(r) \quad (*)
$$

**Example:**
$$
u_g =
\left[
\begin{matrix}
-1 \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right]
\quad
v_g =
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 \\
-1
\end{matrix}
\right]
\quad
u_h =
\left[
\begin{matrix}
0 \\
-1
\end{matrix}
\right]
\quad
v_h =
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 \\
1
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$

This gives
$$
g(r) =
\left[
\begin{matrix}
r - 1 \\
1 - 2r
\end{matrix}
\right]
\quad
h(r) =
\left[
\begin{matrix}
r \\
2r - 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
\quad
g(s) =
\left[
\begin{matrix}
s - 1 \\
1 - 2s
\end{matrix}
\right]
\quad
h(s) =
\left[
\begin{matrix}
s \\
2s - 1
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
and thus for two different family lines ($r \ne s$):
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & -1 \\
4r-2 &  2 - 4s
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
t \\
t'
\end{matrix}
\right]
= 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
s - r \\
2 (r - s)
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
The first row gives $t' = t + r - s$ and the second row
$$
2(r-s) = (4r-2)t + (2-4s)(t+r-s) = 4(r-s) t + (2-4s)(r-s) \iff \\
4s(r-s) = 4(r-s) t \iff \\
t = s
$$

and thus $t' = r$. The intersection point results to
$$
p(r,s) =
f_r(s) =
f_s(r)
$$
however we want $r \to s$ and thus: 
$$
p(r) =
f_r(r) =
\left[
\begin{matrix}
(r-1)(1-r) + r^2 \\
(1-2r)(1-r) + (2r-1) r
\end{matrix}
\right]
= 
\left[
\begin{matrix}
2r - 1 \\
4r^2 -4r + 1 
\end{matrix}
\right] 
$$
Substituting $x = 2 r - 1 \iff r = (x + 1) / 2$ and remembering $r \in [0, 1]$ we get
$$
p(x) =
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x \\
4\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)^2 -4 \frac{x+1}{2} + 1 
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
x \\
x^2
\end{matrix}
\right] 
$$
which is the graph of a parabola.

[image: Graph of the parabola as parametric plot]

**Note:**

I picked the example to correspond to a nice symmetric V shape. 
Equation (*) holds for general situations, e.g. a V with a longer and a shorter arm. In those cases, other envelopes, if at all, arise!

E.g. it is possible to arrange the guiding lines as a | | shape, where the result should look like a butterfly or a (boring) stripes pattern, depending on the relative orientations of the guiding lines.

Answer (score 1):

The curve you see is by [definition](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Quadratic_B.C3.A9zier_curves) a quadratic bézier curve which is always a segment of a parabola.